# Swift Do Try Catch behaviour

Tags: swift, try-catch

I was dealing with a class where I have implemented a do-try-catch clause.
Basically the problem is that the code after "try" got executed even though the try fails:

```
Do{
 try jsonparshing(mydata)
code....
}catch{
alert("error")
}
```

Is it correct to locate the code after try?
I don't want that this code get executed if try fails.

Comment: If a `try` fails, execution goes to the `catch`. The code after the failed `try` does not get called.

Comment: Does the method really `throw` an error if it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I would do to debug that behavior:

(1) Does your 'jsonparshing(mydata)' really throw?
1.a. You could check the type of the 'jsonParsing(_:)' for the throws keyword.

1.b. Or you could try to omit the 'do { } catch {}' and 'try' altogether to see if Xcode complain that the function throws and should use try.

// btw. is that a typo? Maybe 'jsonParsing(myData)' is more custom.

(2) Assuming you past check in (1). I.e. the function really throw. Then you could replace your 'jsonParsing(_:)' with a mock one just to convince yourself that the  Swift 'do {} catch {}' does work. There could be something else in your code that might cause the unexpected behavior.

```
enum SimpleError: Error {
    case userError(msg: String)
    case systemError(msg: String)
}

func alwaysThrow() throws  -> () {
    throw SimpleError.userError(msg: "I create error!")
}


do {
    print("before throw")   // printed 
    try alwaysThrow()
    print("after throw")    // not printed
} catch {
    print(error)        // print: "userError("I create error!")\n"
}
```

(3) At this point, if it is not a user/programmer mistake, then focus your attention on the 'jsonParsing(_:)' as there is where the culprit is.